# alias_method_chain and monkey patching

Tags: ruby

I want to monkey patch a method created for `alias_method_chain` but the overwritten method is not called

```
# foo.rb
require 'active_support/core_ext'

class Foo
  def foo
    "original foo"
  end

  def foo_with_flag
    "foo with flag"
  end

  alias_method_chain :foo, :flag
end

# foo_ext.rb
class Foo
  def foo_with_flag
    "overridden foo with flag"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.foo # => "foo with flag"
foo.foo_with_flag # => "overridden foo with flag"
```

How can I make `Foo#foo` use the last implementation of `Foo#foo_with_flag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `alias_method_chain` do the `alias_method :foo, :foo_with_flag` (a *copy* of the first definition), when you redefine `foo_with_flag` `:foo` is still alias'ed to the first definition. You have to do `alias_method :foo, :foo_with_flag` again after the second definition (not the "whole chain").